# Unable to start program due to Access is denied error

Tags: .net, azure, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to run azure function using VS2017 in admin mode. I have window 10 installed in my machine.

But i am getting below error 
[image]

Comment: How did you run admin mode? If I right click Visual Studio icon>choose Run as administrator, the azure function works fine in Visual Studio. The result like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wP4K5.png).

Comment: @JanleyZhang Correct,I did right click on Visual studio icon and Run as administrator still i am getting above error. I think this problem is in window 10.

Comment: Are your Visual Studio login account the same as Windows login account? And you could try to restart VS.

Comment: add full permission to everyone on azure-cli folder, check if that works